# Ckeditor - add ckeditor after load the page on div (contenteditable="true" )

Tags: html, ckeditor

When I added `ckeditor` on div `contenteditable="true"` it worked fine. There is an `add more` button.  When I click on that button, the div is added but `ckeditor` is not loaded. How can I get `ckeditor` to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Creating Classic Editor

What you need to do is to call [`CKEDITOR.replace`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace) method for your each `div[contenteditable="true"]` that was just added to the document.

You can achieve it with a following code:

```
var res = CKEDITOR.document.find( 'div[contenteditable="true"]' ),
    // Your editor config goes here.
    editorConfig = {};

for ( var i = 0; i < res.count(); i++ ) {
    var curElement = res.getItem( i );

    if ( !curElement.getEditor() ) {
        // We only want to process elements that have have no editor yet.
        CKEDITOR.replace( curElement, editorConfig );
    }
}
```

### Inline Editor

If you want to create inline editor instead, you need to repalce `CKEDITOR.replace` with [`CKEDITOR.inline`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline).

```
if ( !curElement.getEditor() ) {
    // We only want to process elements that have have no editor yet.
    CKEDITOR.inline( curElement, editorConfig );
}
```

### More reading:

- [Classic Editing](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed)
- [Inline Editing](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline)